# How to create custom error handler for Mule domain project

Tags: runtime-error, mule, mule-esb

I would like to catch exceptions when run/start domain project.
I have HTTP listeners configured in domain project, if port already used I want to catch those errors.

Answer (score 1):

In Mule 4 you can not catch errors not related to the execution of a flow, ie [System Errors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/error-handling#system_errors). Those errors maybe printed in the log by the runtime, but their handling is not configurable. Even if it were there is no way to recover that kind of error. I recommend to setup some monitoring system to be sure the applications are behaving correctly. For example, to check that the port is open and listening to requests.